# NTT carreer paths

Tags: job, tenure-track, visiting

I am an AbD PhD Candidate in history, currently navigating the complexities of the job market. Recently, I had job talks for both a tenured track position at an R1 PUI institution in another state (Canpus city) and a visiting faculty role at a wealthy private institution in the big city I am living in.

A bit of background: I am a Black woman, not originally from the U.S, with a Master's degree from France and UK, and a career as a editor for academic/academic adjacent German/French press. I am also an author of 3 books.

Throughout my academic journey, I've worked in diverse fields, received numerous awards and fellowships, and authored several books for a mainstream audience. In the last five years, I completed my PhD, published 2 papers in a journal, and signed my fourth book. During my doctoral studies, I gave 14 invited talks at R1 institutions and taught three courses.

Despite my success on the job market, I find myself on the brink of burnout and anxiety due to the level of micro/macro aggression I have to deal with and the general atmosphere in the U.S. The last straw was when I read an article about the suicide of Dr. Antoinette Bonnie Candia-Bailey, a Black Woman VP of Univ of Missouri.

I am almost 40, deeply connected to my community, and while I love research and teaching, I'm not attached to a particular status. The pandemic and life events have been a harsh lesson about centering my life around my career. My wife and I appreciate our life in our current city, where Black queer couples are a banality. I am contemplating stepping back from the tenure track and seeking more flexible positions that align with my current priorities.

I have no anxiety about the job; in fact, I am open to returning to my previous life as a writer or editor for a popular academic adjacent press. However, I am keen on staying in the U.S, teaching, researching, and maintaining health insurance. I am leaning towards the visiting professor path or a research-focused role.

As I stand at this crossroads, I am seeking advice on how to articulate my decision to step away from the tenure track to my faculty advisor and department chair (they really put a lot of pressure on me).

Moreover, I am exploring the possibility of transitioning from Visiting Assistant Professor to Visiting Associate Professor over time. Any insights or suggestions on alternative career paths with flexibility would be immensely valuable.

Comment: Best of luck to you. It sounds as if you have a lot going on, counseling might be a helpful ally in navigating your current waters.

Comment: ‘In the last five years, I completed my PhD’ and now you’re an ‘AbD PhD candidate’? I’m missing something here.

Comment: I submitted (been approved)  the completed manuscript in September, and went for a 4 month parental leave, my faculty advisor (and I) agreed to have the defense this Spring hopefully with a job offer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to at least have a tenure track job offer before you can describe any action as *stepping away* from that path.

I'd be applying for any jobs that possibly interest you and sorting them out once you have multiple offers to choose between. At that point, I think it'll be better to think about those *specific offers* rather than what they are labeled: everything from the job description to the location (including your spouse's preferences).